# HttpURLConnection Delete doesn't work in Android

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

I want to delete an Item from my `RESTful Webservice in Android`. My Webservice looks like this:

```
@DELETE
@Path("/schueler/{id}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void deleteSchueler(@PathParam("id") int id) {
    ManagementDAO.instance.deleteSchueler(id);
}
```

and here is some Android code. First of all the call of the `AsyncTask`:

```
new AsyncDeleteSchueler(getApplicationContext()).execute("http://" + url.getText().toString() + ":8080/A07_Webservice/rest/ManagementService/schueler/" + Integer.parseInt(deleteId.getText().toString()));
```

and the code for this task:

```
public String putJSONToWebservice(String u) {
    int responseCode = 0;

    try {
        URL url = new URL(u);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        connection.setRequestMethod("DELETE");
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setReadTimeout(10000);
        connection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

        connection.connect();
        responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return Integer.toString(responseCode);
}
```

Do you know why the `Delete method` isn't working? PUT, POST etc. work fine but this code doesn't.

Comment: I think DELETE is handled by a POST request. Do you have a documentation of the API you use

Comment: What's error response from your api? There should be an error in log